# How to use javap

Tags: java, command-line, java-native-interface

I must be doing something stupid, because this seems like such a easy operation. For some reason, I just cannot get this command to work for me. I've installed JDK, and I go into the

```
/bin
```

folder. I type:

```
./javap -classpath /home/Matt/workspace/VariablesTestProject/src/ -s VariablesTest.Variable
```

My actual filepath for the class is

```
/home/Matt/workspace/VariablesTestProject/src/VariablesTest/Variable.java
```

The error I get back is:

```
ERROR:Could not find VariablesTest.Variable
```

A command like this works however:

```
./javap -s java.lang.String
```

These are not the only commands I've tried. I've literally tried every variation I can think of, and none of them work. My javac and java commands both work fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javap works against the `.class` bytecode. So point the classpath at the `VariablesTestProject/out` or whatever.

Comment: Did ./javap -classpath /home/Matt/workspace/VariablesTestProject/src/VariablesTest -s Variable; same error

Comment: Where did you compile your code to? Where is `VariablesTest.class`?

Comment: Oh I indeed did something stupid. I thought the command worked on .java files, not complied .class. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

One recent use of javap which I've found is to check which version of JDk compiled a particular class file on Windows:

```
javap -v path to .class file | findstr major
```

This will give you major version number :

> 50 - JDK6, 51 - JDK7, 52 - JDK8, 53 - JDK9.

Answer (score 3):

If you want perform operations using the javap command, first go to the jar location in cmd prompt.

Eg:

`cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib` (Linux)

`cd D:\javasoftware\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre\lib` (Windows)

The above locations are the rt.jar locations. java.lang.String is the one of the classes in this jar.

Using javap you can get the information from this class.

Eg:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib
javap java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

I will make it simple words to understand the use of **Javap** Command in Java .

- **javap** command is a tool or you can say it dissembler which can read class files .

I have sample java program like below.

```
class Bank {
   private int code = 210;

   class SBI {
       void display() {
           System.out.println("Code is "+code);
       }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
       Bank b = new Bank();
       Bank.SBI sbi = b.new SBI();
       sbi.display();
   }
}
```

After compilation I got Bank.class file.Next my friends Subbu and Narasimha asked me compiled version of source file.Later on they want to see what vikram is actually used then they will use the following command to see the basic details like what methods used in this Bank.class file.

```
C:\ >javap Bank.class
Compiled from "Bank.java"
class Bank {
  Bank();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  static int access$000(Bank);
}
```

java has pretty cool tools to check out many features few of them like javaws.**jconsole**,**javaws**,**jmap**,**jhat** and **jinfo**

Answer (score 0):

`javap` is the command used to see the java profile/method declaration of a Inbuilt class/User Defined Class/Interfaces/Abstract Class.

-> If you want to see the methods of a pre defined class then in this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib` you have `rt.jar` if you installed jdk.

-> Extract that rt.jar file in some folder D:\rt and then go to this folder and type
`javap java.util.collection` or `javap java.lang.*` or any other predefined package to see the methods.

-> If you want to see the user defined class methods then go to the workspace\javaproject\specificpackage\bin and then type `javap classname`  and you can see all the methods declaration.